# Ensemble datasets mean in Python

Tags: python, arrays, mean

I am reading all my datasets in one ensemble 'ens1'. As given below.

```
wrf_dict = {"ens1" : [Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_01_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_02_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_03_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_04_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_05_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_06_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_07_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_08_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_09_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_10_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_11_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_12_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_13_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_14_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_15_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_16_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_17_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_18_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_19_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_20_00_00"),
                      Dataset("wrfout_d01_2020-12-03_21_00_00")]}
```

I have read a common variable from all 21 datasets i.e. QCLOUD.

```
LWC = getvar(wrf_dict, "QCLOUD", timeidx=ALL_TIMES)[:,0,:,:]
```

Now I want to take a mean of all 21 QCLOUD variable at each grid location. Can any one suggest me solution

Comment: What is `Dataset`?

Comment: @MaxPowers this is WRF model output in .nc format